# Create Grid in Startup Window Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

Note: I'm new to WPF so this question might be relatively simple.

I'm trying to make a grid using a method, and I'm using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-grid-element) to guide me. Although, it generates the grid in a new window, which I don't want. I want the grid to be in the startup window. I know that if the window I wanted the grid in wasn't the startup window, all I would have to do is just replace `new Window();` with the name of the window I wanted it in.

However, with the way that WPF creates the starting window, I can't find a name to use. I know that there's a [StartupUri Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startupuri(v=vs.110).aspx), but I'm unable to find enough info to help me out, and like I said, I'm new to C#.

Hopefully my description is clear enough, and if it isn't then feel free to tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Set the MainWindow's Content. That said, there is usually no need at all to create UI elements in code. Use DataTemplates instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your `Grid` in the code-behind class of the startup window (`MainWindow.xaml.cs` by default):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Grid myGrid = new Grid();
        myGrid.Width = 250;
        myGrid.Height = 100;
        ...
        Content = myGrid;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is there a way to only generate the grid say, on a button click and not on initialization?

Comment: Yes. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.